# Best way to change React render structure

Tags: javascript, templates, reactjs

I allow to request your opinion. In fact, I think of a way to change the structure of a react component (The DOM). For example, I have a component **Page1**. Normaly, we have this:

```
import React from "react";

class Page1 extends React.Component
{
    ...
    render()
    {
        return (
            /*Here JSX DOM*/
        );
    }
}
```

For change the DOM of this page (according a template), I think this:

```
import React from "react";

class Page1 extends React.Component
{
    ...
    render()
    {
        return Template.get("page1", this.props);
    }

}
```

The *get* method of **Template** class return the JSX DOM according the template define in config:

```
{
    template: "base"
}
```

The Template class:

```
import {template} from "config" // Name of a template

class Template
{
    static get(componentName, props)
    {
        var templatePath = path.join("templates", template);
        return require(templatePath)[componentName](props);
    }
}
```

In templates folder, we can have this structure:

```
templates
    |
    |____base
    |       |
    |       |__index.js
    |       |
    |       |__pag1.tpl.jsx
    |
    |____other
            |
            |__index.js
            |
            |__page1.tpl.jsx
```

And the **page1.tpl.jsx** to base template look like this:

```
import React from "react";

export default function(props) {
   return (
      <div>Hello World !!!</div>
   );
}
```

I 'm interested in you opinion.

Comment: You seem to introduce unnecessary complexity. My *opinion* is that this is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion react components should be as modular as possible, so they will be like an template.

> So, your idea is good, but you should use react components as templates instead of normal es6 classes.

React components can check the (required) properties automatically be defining `propTypes`. Additionally, the syntax will be change from

```
return Template.get("page1", this.props);
```

to

```
return <Page1 {...this.props} />;
```

Wich, in my opinion, is easier to read.

Comment: Thank for you answer !!! Just, I should rename **Page1** component (that render the template) to **Page1Template**

Comment: personally, i don't have the convention to call it `template` or `component` but you can do that, if you want ;-) Pls give a +1 for my time ;-)